# ionic 2 time wise sorting

Tags: sorting, ionic2

how to short my list time wise ascending/ descending order

i have array like this:

```
this.array= [
    {name: A, time: 10:00am},
    {name: b, time: 10:05am},
    {name: c, time: 10:02am},
    {name: e, time: 09:00am}
]
```

i want to show this array **time wise acceding** order like:

```
this.array= [
    {name: e, time: 09:00am},
    {name: A, time: 10:00am},
    {name: c, time: 10:02am},
    {name: b, time: 10:05am},
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: @Dipankar please tell if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use MomentJS:

```
array= [
  {'name': 'A', 'time': '10:00am'},
  {'name': 'b', 'time': '10:05am'},
  {'name': 'c', 'time': '10:02am'},
  {'name': 'e', 'time': '09:00am'}
]

sorted = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    aT = new moment(a.time, 'HH:mm:ss a');
    bT = new moment(b.time, 'HH:mm:ss a');
    return aT.isBefore(bT) ? -1 : bT.isBefore(aT) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

To get MomentJS do:

```
npm install --save moment
```

then use it:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/.